# How to cancel WebClient reactive call before initiating a new one when first one is in waiting to be retried

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, spring-reactive

I’m using WebClient to create a call to send status updates to an endpoint as below:

```java
public Disposable updateStatus(Status status) {
    return WebClient.create("http://server:7777")
      .post()
      .body(status, Status.class)
      .exchange()
      .retryBackoff(2, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
      .subscribe();
}
```

The endpoint I’m calling is not 100% available (might not be able to reach it because of lets say network issue). That is why I’m using `retryBackoff`.

In the below scenario

```
time
0    Send status
1    Because of network issue it throws exception and schedules a try in 30 seconds (time 0 + 30) 
2    Another status is available and need to be sent. However, the first one need to be cancelled.
```

My question is how can I cancel the call in time 1 and send the call in time 2 instead. In time 1, it will try to resend again because of  retryBackoff.

Should I keep a reference of the returned Disposable and call `dispose` on it before calling `updateStatus` again? What is the proper way of cancelling calls?